# Prove that $F(A \coprod B) = F(A) \ast F(B)$ in $\mathsf{Grp}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, category-theory

The problem statement above is from *Algebra: Chapter 0* by Paolo Aluffi.

As additional context, $F(A)$ was defined to be initial in the category whose objects consist of set-function, group pairs $(j, G)$, $j: A \to G$. The group $F(A) \ast F(B)$ was not explicitly constructed, but it was stated that it is a coproduct in $\mathsf{Grp}$. At this point in the book, $A \coprod B$ has been proven to be a coproduct in $\mathsf{Set}$.

So far, I have used the universal property for coproducts to construct a homomorphism $F(A) \ast F(B) \to G$ for any arbitrary group $G$, given a function $f: A \coprod B \to G$; I'm not quite sure if I'm done or I still need to prove that the diagram commutes. I've outlined my proof so far below; any tips/hints would be appreciated!

First, I noted that because of the universal property of coproducts in $\mathsf{Set}$, combined with functions $A \to F(A) \to F(A) \ast F(B)$ and $B \to F(B) \to F(A) \ast F(B)$, there exists a unique set-function $\varphi: A \coprod B \to F(A) \ast F(B)$ that makes everything commute.

Now, consider an arbitrary group $G$, as well as some function $f: A \coprod B \to G$. Since there are inclusions of $A$ and $B$ into $A \coprod B$, $f$ uniquely determines functions from $A$ and $B$ into $G$. It then follows from the universal property of free groups that $f$ uniquely determines homomorphisms from $F(A)$ and $F(B)$ to $G$.

Thus, we can use the universal property of coproducts in $\mathsf{Grp}$ to obtain a homomorphism $\sigma: F(A) \ast F(B) \to G$ uniquely determined by $f$.

Am I done here? In particular, is it guaranteed that $\sigma\varphi = f$ at this point?

Comment: Your question is lacking a little context. What exactly are your definitions, and what are you asked to prove? In particular, if you already know that $F(A)*F(B)$ is a coproduct, and you know the universal properties for free groups, and you know that $A\coprod B$ is a coproduct in $Set$, then there isn't much to say...

Comment: @ziggurism I have added additional context.

Comment: Once you know that $\sigma\varphi = f$, you will indeed be done

Comment: @Max I've been thinking about it, does this argument work? We know that $A \coprod B$ contains an isomorphic copy of $A$. So, restricting ourselves to that isomorphic copy, the inclusion of $A$ into the coproduct has an inverse. I do know for a fact that all operations from $A$ to $G$ commute, and so in that case, $\sigma\varphi = f$. Proceed similarly for $B$, and so for all of $A \coprod B$, $\sigma\varphi = f$.

Comment: Yes, it suffices to show that $\sigma\phi$ and $f$ agree on $A$ and $B$ to conclude that they are equal